# Get query results as a file to send to an external sFtp Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have created an Sql Server instance in *Amazon RDS*.

What I want to do is a scenario like this:

1. Run a `SELECT` query on a database that resides on my cloud Sql Server
2. Output the results of the query to a *.csv* file.
3. Send the file in (2) to an external SFTP server.

What I'm not sure of is:

1. Where will the file in step (2) land on in absence of a local server in which we create the file?
2. Does AWS have an FTP solution. I have used *S3* but can files in S3 be accessed like a normal FTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS won't be able to perform these operations without help.  You'll either need an EC2 instance or some other *server*, be it locally hosted or other on which you can run a BCP job, SSIS package, or other home-baked solution.  RDS is just the database engine, and there's nothing native within SQL Server on RDS that allows for external file manipulation and/or transfer.

From Amazon's [Importing and Exporting SQL Server Data Using Other Methods](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Snapshots.html) page:

> **Exporting Data from SQL Server on Amazon RDS**
>
> - **Native database backup using a full backup file (.bak)** – Using .bak files to backup databases is heavily optimized, and is usually the fastest way to export data. For more information, see [Importing and Exporting SQL Server Databases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html).
> - **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard** – For more information, see SQL Server [Import and Export Wizard](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Snapshots.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Exporting.SSIEW).
> - **SQL Server Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard and bcp utility** – For more information, see [SQL Server Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard and bcp Utility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Snapshots.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Exporting.SSGPSW).

Another option may be to utilize AWS Lamdba to do this as well.  I've not worked with this in much depth personally, but [this article from Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/) describes a similar process for exporting data from Oracle and PostgreSQL and in the final sections of the article state this is possible for SQL Server as well.

Comment: So, is it possible to land the .csv file on an EC2 instance? And then put Ftp Uploader program there as well?

Comment: Yes, so long as the connection is established from the EC2 instance via sqlcmd, BCP, SSIS, etc.

Comment: What I mean is can I install Sql Server Management Studio on the EC2 instance and then configure my jobs there? Because one cannot run a scheduled job on RDS without an external server right?

Comment: Jobs won't work with an RDS instance either, so your schedule will need to be managed by something else, for instance a Windows Scheduled task on the EC2 instance would work.  The Task would need to call a PowerShell script or batch file that would manage the workflow of your needs (e.g. export data, FTP elsewhere, etc.).

Comment: I see. So I guess I am going to need EC2. Sorry if I sound naive, but will my EC2 instance basically be a Windows environment in which I can create scheduled tasks and put my FTP uploader program?

Comment: Yes, it's a VM essentially.  As I also stated in my answer, if you want to sidestep an EC2 instance, you may be able to work your process into a [Lambda-based solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/) instead.